# Can a fighter with a healing fracture or dislocation get medically cleared to fight?

Tags: injury, safety, medical-advice

I understand there are professional fights in which one of the fighters may suffer an injury but they continue to fight on and may even win the fight in the end. However at the same time, there is also a medical clearance process which checks if a fighter is medically fit (not injured) to take part in an upcoming bout. In MMA, my understanding is that there is a comprehensive physical done along with scans, x-rays etc, so the physician doing the check will have a very good idea of the fighter's health before making a decision.

I would like to know if there is a general threshold deemed acceptable for medical clearance, when a fighter has some injuries but is still able to fight? For example, if the physician knows/finds that a fighter has fractures or a recent dislocation that are still healing, would that generally be considered a no go for clearing them? Or are there circumstances where this kind of injury would be considered ok? Of course there would be a certain amount of pressure on the physician, especially if they are looking after someone famous, to provide the medical clearance, but I am looking at more of a perfect world scenario. This also assumes that the fighter themselves accepts the limitations that the injuries may put on them but still wants to go ahead anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at answering this question based on the research I have done, happy for others to comment or add another better answer.

On [this website](https://www.iscfmma.com/ISCFRules15.htm), fractures incur a 180 day medical suspension, and joint injuries 60 day medical suspensions. Therefore the logical answer would be that clearance wouldn't be given until this period has lapsed, although the physician does still have the ability to clear a fighter before this time period.

[This website](https://www.mmamania.com/ufc-medical-suspensions-and-injuries) is also a good reference as it has a list of recent medical suspensions and the injuries they are related to, including dislocations and fractures.